# Copying and mirroring weight paint

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I am using Blender 2.8

On my last work I encountered trouble with **mirroring my weight paints**.
My bones are named correctly with R and L prefixes.
It may look like everything work correctly, I press Mirror, under weights panel,
and my paints are **transferred** to another side.
   The only problem is **I want them to be copied to another side**, not **transferred**,
because my model is **symmetrical**, and I want same weights on both sides.

Thank you in advance ;).